# SQL Server link to MySQL reports "using password: no"

Tags: sql-server, mysql, linked-server

I would like to access a MySQL database from within SQL Server.  I created a system DSN, and it tests OK.  I created a linked server in SQL Server:

- Provider = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- Product name = MySQL
- Data source = (the name of the DSN)
- Security = one entry for each of my local logins, with my MySQL user name and password

However, if I try to test it I get this error message:

```
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
server "X".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "X" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC
5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

The password is most definitely set, and works just fine in MySQL Workbench.  It's an admin on MySQL.  Both machines are local.  I tried adding my creds as the default ("for a login not in the list, use this security context"); no change.

I set up my DSN as 64-bit, matching my OS, using "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver", which I gather was installed with the MySQL engine and/or MySQL Workbench.  The 32-bit ODBC app offers the usual Portuguese drivers (why Portuguese?!) - Access, dBase, Excel, Paradox, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is the choice of ODBC driver.  64-bit seems to be OK, but by replacing the "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" with "MySQL ODBC 5.3 **ANSI** Driver", the problem went away.

The two drivers are discussed on [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889046/difference-between-ansi-and-unicode-drivers-of-mysql), the [MySQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,658236,658394), and the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation.html), but they do not make it clear that a SQL Server linked server requires the ANSI driver.  At least, with my configuration (pretty much all defaults, it's a new installation, nothing unusual I can think of), the ANSI driver worked and the Unicode driver did not.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this installing a linked server to MySQL with the "MySQL 8.0" connector. The same error message in the OP occurred when trying the 64-bit versions of both the ANSI and the Unicode connectors on 64-bit Windows Server 2016 host/SQL Server 2019 Standard.

In my case, the issue had to do with the connection string, specifically the `PWD=MyPa$$word` portion. Replacing it with the equivalent `password=MyPa$$word` fixed the issue.

Credit to this [MSSQL Tips article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4570/access-mysql-data-from-sql-server-via-a-linked-server/), which has a chart of the possible connection string parameters.